# Creating a slider for div appended with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I want to create a slider for a json data i am calling through ajax and loading into a div. 
I am using the slick library to do so. But it's not working.
Here is the code. 
The ajax call and loading it into a div.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"{% url 'paper-api:PaperDetails' %}",
    method:"GET",
    success: function(data){
        var numTests = 0;
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            var numberTests = key;
            numTests = 1 + numTests
            var topics = value.topics.toString()
            var all_topics = topics.replace(/,/g,"<br>");
            $(".testSlider").after(
                "<div class='col-sm-2 col-md-4 slide'   id ='newTests'>"+
                    "<div class='thumbnail'>"+      
                        "<div class='caption'>"+
                            "<h3 class='text-center' style='font-weight:bold;'>"+value.subject+"</h3>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'>"+value.num_questions+' questions'+" </h4>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'>Created By:  </h4>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'><strong>"+value.creator+"</strong>  </h4>"+
                            "<h4> Topics </h4>"+
                            "<ul id="+key+"newTopics>"+all_topics+"</ul>"+
                            "<button name='test_id' value="+key+" onclick='loadTopics("+key+")' class='btn btn-success' id="+key+"testID>"+"Show all topics"+"</button>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+
                            "<div class='text-center'>"+
                                "<form action = {% url 'QuestionsAndPapers:conductTest' %} method='get'>"+
                                    "<button type='submit' name='onlineTestid' class='btn btn-primary' value="+key+" onclick='testTake()'>"+"Take Test"+"</button>"+
                                "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>"
            )
        });
    },
    complete: function(data){
        $('.testSlider').slick();
        $("#tests").hide();
    },
    error: function(data){
    }               
});
```

Now here is the the body code:

```
<div class='testSlider'>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript for slick slider:

```
$('.testSlider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

It's still not working. 
**However if I manually add div to testSlider div then it starts working. Thats why my suspicion lies on ajax loading.**

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing closing `</div>` in your ajax callback function:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"{% url 'paper-api:PaperDetails' %}",
    method:"GET",
    success: function(data){
        var numTests = 0;
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            var numberTests = key;
            numTests = 1 + numTests
            var topics = value.topics.toString()
            var all_topics = topics.replace(/,/g,"<br>");
            $(".testSlider").after(
                "<div class='col-sm-2 col-md-4 slide'   id ='newTests'>"+
                    "<div class='thumbnail'>"+      
                        "<div class='caption'>"+
                            "<h3 class='text-center' style='font-weight:bold;'>"+value.subject+"</h3>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'>"+value.num_questions+' questions'+" </h4>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'>Created By:  </h4>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'><strong>"+value.creator+"</strong>  </h4>"+
                            "<h4> Topics </h4>"+
                            "<ul id="+key+"newTopics>"+all_topics+"</ul>"+
                            "<button name='test_id' value="+key+" onclick='loadTopics("+key+")' class='btn btn-success' id="+key+"testID>"+"Show all topics"+"</button>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+
                            "<div class='text-center'>"+
                                "<form action = {% url 'QuestionsAndPapers:conductTest' %} method='get'>"+
                                    "<button type='submit' name='onlineTestid' class='btn btn-primary' value="+key+" onclick='testTake()'>"+"Take Test"+"</button>"+
                                "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>"
// -->  Missing "</div>" goes here  <--
            )
        });
    },
    complete: function(data){
        $('.testSlider').slick();
        $("#tests").hide();
    },
    error: function(data){
    }               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you trying call slick in success:function(){//call slick}

```js
$.ajax({
    url:"{% url 'paper-api:PaperDetails' %}",
    method:"GET",
    success: function(data){
        var numTests = 0;
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            var numberTests = key;
            numTests = 1 + numTests
            var topics = value.topics.toString()
            var all_topics = topics.replace(/,/g,"<br>");
            $(".testSlider").after(
                "<div class='col-sm-2 col-md-4 slide'   id ='newTests'>"+
                    "<div class='thumbnail'>"+      
                        "<div class='caption'>"+
                            "<h3 class='text-center' style='font-weight:bold;'>"+value.subject+"</h3>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'>"+value.num_questions+' questions'+" </h4>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'>Created By:  </h4>"+
                            "<h4 class='text-center'><strong>"+value.creator+"</strong>  </h4>"+
                            "<h4> Topics </h4>"+
                            "<ul id="+key+"newTopics>"+all_topics+"</ul>"+
                            "<button name='test_id' value="+key+" onclick='loadTopics("+key+")' class='btn btn-success' id="+key+"testID>"+"Show all topics"+"</button>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+
                            "<div class='text-center'>"+
                                "<form action = {% url 'QuestionsAndPapers:conductTest' %} method='get'>"+
                                    "<button type='submit' name='onlineTestid' class='btn btn-primary' value="+key+" onclick='testTake()'>"+"Take Test"+"</button>"+
                                "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>"
   
            )
        });
          //call slick
        $('.testSlider').slick({
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3
         });
        
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys! 
But I found the a working solution. 
I was using .after to load data, and that created divs after the slick slider div.
Instead changing after to append creates divs inside the slick slider div and then it works.